# jQuery clickable links with setInterval

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have two text links which go to two different URLs, and the text changes from one text to another every 7secs.

I have tried adding click events but couldn't get it to work properly.

the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function() {
$('#rollover').fadeOut(500, function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var textOne = "Join our facebook group";
    var textTwo = "Join our LinkedIn group connect Scientists today";
    $this.text($this.text() == textOne ? textTwo : textOne);  
    $this.fadeIn(500);
});
}, 7000);   

});
```

html:

```
<p id="rollover">Join our LinkedIn group connect Scientists today</p>
```

Comment: is the fadein/fadeout working as expected?

Comment: It seems work normally, check here http://jsfiddle.net/athd6/

Comment: Yeah its working on my end too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You mean like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/rfpSL/1/

as in change the `<p>` to an `<a>` and add:

```
        var linkOne = "http://url-one.com";
        var linkTwo = "http://url-two.com";

        $this.attr('href', $this.attr('href') == linkOne ? linkTwo : linkOne);
```

Comment: Thanks Serj you are on the money! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is in this line:

```
$this.text($this.text() == textOne ? textTwo : textOne);
```

First of all, I'd recommend renaming $this to self, just in case there's some sort of conflict there.

```
self.text(self.text() == textOne ? textTwo : textOne);
```

Third, this does actually work fine... as shown in the fiddle shown in a comment.

http://jsfiddle.net/athd6/

Comment: Thanks Christian, it is working but what im trying to do is have the "textOne" link to a URL and "textTwo" link to a different url.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () 
{
      change();
});


function change(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#rollover').fadeOut(500, function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var textOne = "Join our facebook group";
            var textTwo = "Join our LinkedIn group connect Scientists today";
            $this.text($this.text() == textOne ? textTwo : textOne);  
            $this.fadeIn(500);
            change();
        });
        }, 7000); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
var textOne = "Join our facebook group";
var textTwo = "Join our LinkedIn group connect Scientists today";
var isRotated=true;
var rotateText=function(){
    setInterval(function(){        
        var text=isRotated?textOne:textTwo;
          $("#rollover").text(text);      
        isRotated=!isRotated;
    }, 7000);
};

rotateText();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UQk5h/1/

Answer (score -1):

try next

```
    $this.html($this.text() == textOne ? textTwo : textOne);
```